# Where is MSOLEDBSQL provider driver? "The 'MSOLEDBSQL' provider is not registered on the local machine."

Tags: connectivity, oledb, tls-1.2

This has been going on. At first MS said they will not support TLS1.2 for OLEDB then they said, they will. [You can read about it here, where they said, the support comes in March 2018](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlnativeclient/2017/10/06/announcing-the-new-release-of-ole-db-driver-for-sql-server/comment-page-1/#comment-11495)

Now it looks like [package has arrived](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2936603/sql-server-2014-build-versions). I installed it. Then I ran soft without change to connection string using old style `Provider=sqloledb`. That was expected to fail and it did. I changed to new style `Provider=MSOLEDBSQL` (see first link). And now I get

> "The 'MSOLEDBSQL' provider is not registered on the local machine."

Ok. I didn't install provider after all. But I can't find it either. I thought, may be this is part of Native Client update. But that came out Jan 2018. I installed it, it didn't break anything, it didn't fix anything. Then I came across [this provider](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/snac-lifecycle-explained/) that was just released. Installed it. This seem to be new ODBC version.

Bottom line, where do I get `MSOLEDBSQL`? Thank you

Comment: The new driver hasn't been released yet. It's still March.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new OLE DB driver, [MSOLEDBSQL](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56730), was released today. This new driver includes the support for the latest TLS 1.2 standards and is backwards compatible with SQL Server Native Client 11 (SQLNCLI11). See [the Microsoft SQLNCLi team blog announcement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlnativeclient/2018/03/30/released-microsoft-ole-db-driver-for-sql-server/).

Comment: An interesting question. The oledb driver we use now also supports legacy Oracle connectivity. Is this new driver fully supports that? I mean, I can unit test that.... anything off your hand?

Comment: @T.S., MSOLEDBSQL is only for Microsoft SQL Server connectivity. Are you saying you have a single third party OLE DB driver that supports connectivity to both Microsoft SQL Server and Oracle? I wasn't aware one existed.

Comment: It is not third party. This is microsoft's own oledb provider that we use. Of course, I might confusing here. We use OleDbDataReader, OleDbConnection, etc. Which, of course connects using different drivers because connection string is declared differently for each DB. Never mind. This is me. You're right. This is sql server driver, oracle uses old one. On the good news, we started moving to native client while ago and now we're making a push to eliminate oledb. But we still have legacy components in the field that want TLS 1.2. Currently ap uses no less than 4 providers. Thank you

Comment: The driver's Provider name is "MSOLEDBSQL19", not "MSOLEDBSQL". Another example of Microsoft obfuscating necessary components.

Comment: @Suncat2000, MS follows the best practice of changing the driver name when there are [breaking changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/major-version-differences) to the interface. This also allows side-by-side installations with the old and new driver until apps are migrated.